# how to promote a context class?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I'm creating some kind of filtering system, which is based on that the different elements accept/produce the same kind of 'context'.

For example with the following, the process can be modelled:

```
{generate_numbers(1..100)} --> {is_prime} --> {output}
```

The context can be a simple 'HashMap'. `generate_numbers` creates contexts where 'x' is set to some number `is_prime` uses this context, looks for 'x' and puts 'prime'=true/false accordingly.

pros:

- flexibility (easily extendable further (HashMap))

cons:

- typeless values are casted all over the place

---

It is also a viable approach to declare everything as a field in the 'context', but this way the easily extendability is sacrificed (i can live with that)

---

But...the situation is a bit more complicated because these transformator elements are scattered all over the application's packages:

```
{generate_numbers(1..100)} --> {is_prime} --> {calc(f_1)} --> {output}
```

```
{--------------- pkg_A ------------------} | {--------- pkg_B -------}
```

So there are parts where pkg_A does some work, then there are places where pkg_B parts process the context --> that's why i would like to mix the two methods

---

I've come up with the following ideas:

#### option 1

- say i've named the basic HashMap containing context E
- create subclasses of E where some entries are presented in field for which  getters/setters are availibe
- in every processing function cast the incoming argument into the required class type

pro:

- relatively easy to implement

con:

- should syncronize the HashMap content w/ the field
- more than one way to access a value can cause confusion

#### option 2

- create some 'tool' classes which do the casting

pro:

- no runtime casting for a subclass at every function

con:

- access is always translated down to HashMap access
- there is a casting every time a field is read

#### option 3

i'm entirely wrong, i should address the problem in a different way

UPDATE:

with "how to promote a context class?" i mean that how can i make a relatively convienient context which will carry all the messy stuff the application is working on, because in the current workflow these informations are blurred with the control logic

Answer (score 1):

I believe you shoudl switch to [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) :D.
Scala is a functional language with OOP design which runs on Java Virtual Machine and supports what you just mentioned and has a powerful pattern matching engine.

The other way might involve simulating functional paradigm in Java, which has actually crossed my mind a few days ago, but I had too much work and forgot about it :D.

Basically, what I was thinking back them is that you should have an interface

```
public interface Functionalizable {
    public void map(Function f);
}
```

Where `Function` would also be an interface which you could extend to write your own functions. Then, one such example (maybe bad, but those were my thought while I was traveling to work in a train) could be like this:

```
public class FunctionList extends ArrayList implements Functionalizable {
    public void map(Function f) {
        // iterate over the elements of a list
        // applying the function f on each of them
    }
}
```

and you could call it like this:

```
List l = new FunctionList();
// add some data
l.map(
    new Function() {
        // some function
    }
)
```

Of course, none of this code is actually compilable, but only whows what I've been thinking about. And yes, introducing functional paradigm in Java is a pain, so once more, my best advice is to stick with a real functional language, like Scala. :D

Comment: this is part of a refactoring run, so switching language is not really an option; but scala looks very intresting - i will read more on scala

Comment: I tried doing something like that myself, with some success: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484235/implementing-simple-functional-like-paradigm-in-java-collections-and-type-castin

Answer (score 0):

Trying to pass around metadata will make a maintenance headache. Instead, you want a [functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) solution, but in particular it appears you want to handle [list comprehensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension) - in your example the `generate_numbers` function. While you could do this by rolling your own - as @Lopina suggests - by creating a set of [function objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object) I think the better path is using an existing Java library.

In particular Google [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has a number of tools for working against Java collections in this manner - the [functional idioms](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained) are what you want. You'll have to write your own functions - in this case Guava [Predicates](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html) - to use within the Guava's framework, but I think it provides right tools and level of abstraction for the problem you describe. [I found this question's answer particularly helpful understanding predicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955043/predicate-in-java).

## Example Guava Code

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import com.google.common.base.Predicate;
import com.google.common.collect.*;

public class PrimeFinder {
    static Predicate<Integer> isPrimeToTenThousand = new Predicate<Integer>() {
        private boolean[] primes = new boolean[10000];
        {
            // prime detection algorithm from
            // http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-determine-a-prime-number-in-java/
            // will contain true or false values for the first 10,000 integers
            Arrays.fill(primes, true); // assume all integers are prime.
            primes[0] = primes[1] = false; // we know 0 and 1 are not prime.
            for (int i = 2; i < primes.length; i++) {
                // if the number is prime,
                // then go through all its multiples and make their values false.
                if (!primes[i]) continue;
                for (int j = 2; i * j < primes.length; j++)
                    primes[i * j] = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean apply(Integer number) {
            return primes[number];
        }
    };

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ImmutableSortedSet<Integer> positiveIntegersTo100 = Ranges.open(1, 100).asSet(DiscreteDomains.integers());
        Iterable<Integer> primeNumbersTo100 = Iterables.filter(positiveIntegersTo100, isPrimeToTenThousand);
        // output: [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
        System.out.println(primeNumbersTo100);
    }
}
```

Finally, this other question and its answers on how to simulate [Python list comprehensions in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/899138/470838) should be helpful.

Comment: you have leaved the 'how to promote a context class?' question open...i'm not really looking for a functional programming library; in your example you ignored the that i sad that in the context there is a 'x' variable which holds the number and a 'prime' which is true/false whenever it's prime or not...i don't really understand

Comment: @Zoltán Nagy: In your example, does calc(f_1) act on all values 1-100, or just the primes?

Comment: on all of the context; i used it because the example is clearer this way....in the real application a bunch of things are computed at different parts of the program, and used elsewhere...