# Implementing simple functional-like paradigm in Java collections and type casting

Tags: java, generics, collections, casting, functional-programming

I've recently started working in Scala and that was my first real contact with a functional paradigm. Although I'm a big fan of Java and, I admit, it lacks functional paradigm sometimes.

That's why I recently started a a mini pet-project to see if such thing, to a degree, could be achieved in Java.

I started with a simple modification of an array list, and this is what I have so far:

---

An interface any collection needs to implement in order to offer applying functions to it's elements:

```
public interface Functionalizable<E> {
    public Collection<E> apply(Function<E> f);
}
```

An interface that defines a method for applying the function on a single element:

```
public interface Function<E> {
    public E apply(E e);
}
```

A concrete class backed by an array list that allows applying functions on it's elements:

```
public class FunctionArrayList<E> implements List<E>, Functionalizable<E> {
    private List<E> list;

    //implemented methods from `List` interface and ctors

    @Override
    public List<E> apply(Function<E> f) {

        List<E> applied = new FunctionArrayList<>(this.list.size());

        for (E e : this.list) {
            applied.add(f.apply(e));
        }

        return applied;
    }
}
```

I've written s small test method for Integer and it works OK:

Code:

```
    List<Integer> listOfIntegersBefore = new FunctionArrayList<>();
    listOfIntegersBefore.add(-1);
    listOfIntegersBefore.add(0);
    listOfIntegersBefore.add(1);
    listOfIntegersBefore.add(2);
    listOfIntegersBefore.add(3);
    listOfIntegersBefore.add(4);

    System.out.println("Before<Integer>: " + listOfIntegersBefore.toString());

    List<Integer> listOfIntegersAfter = ((FunctionArrayList<Integer>) listOfIntegersBefore).apply(new Function<Integer>() {

        @Override
        public Integer apply(Integer e) {
            return (e + 1);
        }
    });

    System.out.println("After<Integer> : " + listOfIntegersAfter.toString());
```

Output:

```
Before<Integer>: [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
After<Integer> : [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

---

However, when I try a tad more complex thing with List, I end up with much type-casting, which I don't like (and I'd like to avoid it as much as possible).
Code:

```
    List<List<Integer>> listOfListOfIntegersBefore = new FunctionArrayList<>();

    List<Integer> temp = new FunctionArrayList<>();
    temp.add(1);
    listOfListOfIntegersBefore.add(temp);

    temp = new FunctionArrayList<>();
    temp.add(1);
    temp.add(2);
    listOfListOfIntegersBefore.add(temp);

    temp = new FunctionArrayList<>();
    temp.add(1);
    temp.add(2);
    temp.add(3);
    listOfListOfIntegersBefore.add(temp);

    temp = new FunctionArrayList<>();
    temp.add(1);
    temp.add(2);
    temp.add(3);
    temp.add(4);
    listOfListOfIntegersBefore.add(temp);

    List<List<Integer>> listOfListOfIntegersAfter = (List<List<Integer>>) ((Functionalizable<List<Integer>>) listOfListOfIntegersBefore).apply(new Function<List<Integer>>() {

        @Override
        public List<Integer> apply(List<Integer> e) {
            List<Integer> list = new FunctionArrayList<>(e);

            return ((FunctionArrayList<Integer>) list).apply(new Function<Integer>() {

                @Override
                public Integer apply(Integer e) {
                    return (e + 1);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    System.out.println("Before<List<Integer>>: " + listOfListOfIntegersBefore);
    System.out.println("After<List<Integer>> : " + listOfListOfIntegersAfter);
```

Output:

```
Before<List<Integer>>: [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
After<List<Integer>> : [[2], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

---

As I have already mentioned, I would like to avoid casting. Plus, Eclipse warns me about `Type safety: Unchecked cast from List<List<Integer>> to Functionalizable<List<Integer>>` on this line:

```
List<List<Integer>> listOfListOfIntegersAfter = (List<List<Integer>>) ((Functionalizable<List<Integer>>) listOfListOfIntegersBefore).apply(new Function<List<Integer>>() {
    ...
}
```

Is there an elegant way to accomplish that?

Comment: There's no question that I can see.

Comment: I obviously didn't express it clearly in the wall of text I typed. It's at the bottom of the post now :D

Comment: the question appears to be "how do i get rid of the casting". but i'm too lazy to read all of this. java is an annoying language to write functional code in. better wait for closure support (java 8) or use another language.

Comment: "Sometimes"? Why not just look at lambdaj?

Comment: Have a look at [Functional Idioms in Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained) and check the source code of the functional classes!

Comment: Have a look at Functional Idioms in Guava...and check out why trying to make Java into something it isn't is usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making your own life hard.

```
List<List<Integer>> listOfListOfIntegersBefore = new FunctionArrayList<>();
[...]
((FunctionArrayList<Integer>) listOfIntegersBefore).apply
```

Why not store it as a `FunctionArrayList` in the first place? 
Of course you have to cast it this way.

Anyway, I find wrapping each list in a functional list a bit annoying, and I'd rather do it with simple static methods:

```
public interface F<S, T> { T apply(S s); }


public final class FunctionalStuff {
  private FunctionalStuff() {}


  public <S, T> static List<T> map(Collection<? extends S> collection,
                                   F<? super S, ? extends T> func) {
    final List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>(collection.size()); 
    for (S source : collection)
      result.add(func.apply(source)); 
    return result;
  }


  public <S, T> static List<S> filter(Collection<? extends S> collection,
                                      F<? super S, Boolean> predicate) {
    final List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>(collection.size()); 
    for (S source : collection)
      if (predicate.apply(source))
        result.add(source); 
    return result; 
  }

  // etc etc.
}
```

Anyways, please note: I don't advise you to do functional style coding in Java. Wait for closures which will be added in Java 8.

Alternatively use a language that embraces functional style: Scala, Javascript, Clojure, Lisp, Mathematica, etc etc, there's a ton of them! Even c(++) seems less annoying at this than Java.

Comment: The argument types for your `map()` and `filter()` functions should be `Iterable<? extends S>` (unless you're going to size the `ArrayList` to match the size of the input collection, in which case `Collection<? extends S>` is better) and `F<? super S, ? extends T>`.

Comment: seems about right, you can consider it code pseudo code in java syntax :) feel free to change it though!

Comment: I went ahead and did that. Please review it to make sure you approve of the changes.

Comment: thx, also i like how you changed the param name to predicate :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to check out [op4j](http://www.op4j.org/). I think they did what you want to achieve in quite a neat way. Either look at the sources and learn from them or simply use the library.