# Is there an equivalent to Python's List Comprehension in Java

Tags: java

I have this Java class called `MyObject` and I want to instantiate a ArrayList/array of 50 non-null `MyObject` elements *in one line*.

So in Python that would be something like:

```py
_list = [MyObject() for i in range(50)]
```

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, 50).mapToObj(i -> new MyObject()).collect(toList())`.

Comment: `Stream.generate(MyObject::new).limit(50).collect(toList())`.

Comment: `List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>(); for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) list.add(new MyObject());` (it's one line... one-liners are overrated.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899138/python-like-list-comprehension-in-java?

Comment: @AndyTurner feels like you should just turn those two into an answer so it can be marked as the right one :)

Answer (score 0):

A solution for plain arrays could look like this (not a one liner though):

```
MyObject[] arr = new MyObject[50];
Arrays.setAll(arr, index -> new MyObject());
```